# Use Vimeo videos inside iPhone/iPad app

Tags: iphone, vimeo

our client's video archive is hosted on vimeo, so I want to know if it is possible to use vimeo videos inside of iOS app so that user could press button and get fullscreen video playing in default video player. Is there any kind of API available for that?

upd: I know that in 2010 there was same question on SO, but maybe things changed during last year.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the video id, and load it into a webview using the vimeo player url. It will open the quicktime player in full screen mode on tap of the play button.

```
urlAddress = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://player.vimeo.com/video/%@",videoID];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
self.requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [YTVimeoExtractor](https://github.com/lilfaf/YTVimeoExtractor) to extract the mp4 url that is usable in MPMoviePlayerViewController.